# unserialize multiple array and echo by passing more than 2 parameter to arraycombine method

Tags: php, arrays

below is my code, as i i have multiple textboxes in my form form hotel detials, that why i have used serialize function to save it. and i am using unserialize function to retrive it.

the below code worked, when only 2 parameters were passed to array combine, but how it's giving me error array_combine() expects exactly 2 parameters,4 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\b2b\view-booking.php on line 84

what alternate i can used to retrieve the result.
is there any other method to do this.
i have been trying solutions since 3 days, posted everywhere.
still no got the solutions.

```html
$queryagent= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM rmt_bookings where b_id='$id'");

while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($queryagent)){

$b_hdest = unserialize($rs['b_hdest']);
$b_hname = unserialize($rs['b_hname']);
$b_hadd = unserialize($rs['b_hadd']);
$b_hcextra = unserialize($rs['b_hcextra']);
//....here i am just retriving 4 for short answers

$hcnt=1;
foreach (array_combine($b_hdest[0],$b_hname[0],$b_hadd[0],$b_hcextra[0]) as $var1=>$var2=>$var3=>$var4)
{
echo"
<tr><td colspan='4'>Hotel Details ".$hcnt."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Destination ".$var1."</td><td>Name ".$var2."</td><td>Address ".$var3."</td><td>Child Extra ".$var4."</td></tr>";
$hcnt++;
}

}
```

i need the output int he following manner.

```html
.mytable table, td, th {    
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
}

.mytable table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

.mytable th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
<table class='mytable'>
<tr><td colspan='4'>Hotel Details 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Destination ".$var1."</td><td>Name ".$var2."</td><td>Address ".$var3."</td><td>Child Extra ".$var4."</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan='4'>Hotel Details 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Destination ".$var1."</td><td>Name ".$var2."</td><td>Address ".$var3."</td><td>Child Extra ".$var4."</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan='4'>Hotel Details 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Destination ".$var1."</td><td>Name ".$var2."</td><td>Address ".$var3."</td><td>Child Extra ".$var4."</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For start, [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) expects only two arguments, both arrays. It doesn't work (and returns `NULL`) when it is invoked with a different number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

try `array_merege` instead of `array_combine`

```
$newarray = array_merege($b_hdest[0],$b_hname[0],$b_hadd[0],$b_hcextra[0]);

print_r($newarray);



foreach($newarray as $new){

  print_r($new);

  }
```

Comment: how can i do that. like <tr><td></td></tr> how can i print it inside this.

Comment: loop through the newly generated array or upated your question with new generated array

Comment: like  echo "<tr><td>".newarray."</td></tr>" like this. or can u please write a sample code.

Comment: $newarray = array_merge($b_hdest[0],$b_hname[0],$b_hadd[0],$b_hcextra[0]);
print_r($newarray);
$hcnt=1;
foreach($newarray as $new){
    
    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Hotel Details ".$hcnt."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Destination ".print_r($new)."</td><td>Name ".print_r($new)."</td><td>Address ".print_r($new)."
    </td><td>Child Extra ".print_r($new)."</td></tr>";
  $hcnt++;

  }    i  have   done   this , is this correct ..after doing this iam gettign error

Comment: is $b_hdest[0],$b_hname[0],$b_hadd[0],$b_hcextra[0] array or not ?

Comment: can you update the question with what $rs['b_hdest'] contains?

Comment: your solution is working, but their is some problem you can check it here  http://b2b.routemate.in/view-booking.php?packid=1

Comment: sir plz help me with the print function, you code work. but i am not able to print it properly, this is my link. http://b2b.routemate.in/view-booking.php?packid=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157233/discussion-between-arun-kumaresh-and-revati).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a mistake in the `foreach` function...
To explain, I'm answering your question.

First of all, you should use array_merge instead of array_combine because array_merge merges the array while array_combine actually makes the first array to be a key and second array to value.

And the `foreach` can fetch only two things at a time like `$var as $key => $value`

complete code_snippet:

Assuming we need to print all array's same id of value like that:

```
$b_h_dest = &$b_hdest;//reference
foreach ( $b_h_dest as $key => $val ) {
    echo "
    <tr><td colspan='4'>Hotel Details ".$hcnt."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Destination ".$b_hdest[$key]."</td><td>Name ".$b_hname[$key]."</td><td>Address ".$b_hadd[$key]."
    </td><td>Child Extra ".$b_hcextra[$key]."</td></tr>";
}
```

**EDIT1:**

Now, the fully understandable and lengthy code to do all the type juggling with loops to do your work:

```
foreach($h_dest as $val) {
    $dest[] = $val;
}
foreach($h_name as $val) {
    $name[] = $val;
}
foreach($h_add as $val) {
    $add[] = $val;
}
foreach($h_cextra as $val) {
    $cextra[] = $val;
}

$count_dest = count($h_dest);
$count_name = count($h_dest);
$count_add = count($h_dest);
$count_cextra = count($h_dest);
if( $count_dest == $count_name && $count_name == $count_add && $count_add == $count_cextra && $count_cextra == $count_dest ){//for verification to disable error
    $count = $count_dest; //using any because all mached
    $count = $count - 1;//count starts with 1 while array starts with 0
    for( $i = 0 ; $i <= $count; $i++ ){
        $new_array_for_markup[] = array('dest' => $dest[$i], 'name' => $name[$i], 'add' => $add[$i], 'cextra' => $cextra[$i]);
    }

}
```

**EDIT2:**

Actually I forgot to mention how to access that:

```
$hcnt = 1;
foreach ( $new_array_for_markup as $val ) {
    echo "
    <tr><td colspan='4'>Hotel Details ".$hcnt."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Destination ".$val['dest']."</td><td>Name ".$val['name']."</td><td>Address ".$val['add']."
    </td><td>Child Extra ".$val['cextra']."</td></tr>";
    $hcnt++;
}
```

Comment: by using your method i am getting the following error : : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @aminesh-sahu : i am getting the following error by using your method "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: var_dump your $b_hdest (before this answer's code)and post your result!!

Comment: bool(false) 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @aminesh-sahu  i have done this, please correct me if there is any mistake  var_dump($b_hdest);
$hcnt=1;
$b_h_dest = $b_hdest;
foreach ( $b_h_dest as $key => $val ) {
    echo "
    <tr><td colspan='4'>Hotel Details ".$hcnt."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Destination ".$b_hdest[$key]."</td><td>Name ".$b_hname[$key]."</td><td>Address ".$b_hadd[$key]."
    </td><td>Child Extra ".$b_hcextra[$key]."</td></tr>";
    $hcnt++;
}

Comment: what your $b_hdest is boolean value (true/false) then why to use foreach ($b_dest as an array)??check all variables you have with unserialize are they array or not foreach only works for array $b_hdest, $b_hname, $b_hadd, $b_hcextra

Comment: none of my variable are boolean, sir u can check here. http://b2b.routemate.in/view-booking.php?packid=1 , here u can see the array values showing.

Comment: u can see in the below section, the hotel details. i need the output format in 1)hoteldetails 1 after than hoteldetails2,  here the outpur is getting all mixxed. u can check the link i have given.

Comment: check now!! testes with my localhost apache php session

Comment: see edit1 and edit2 and if this solved and make your day please do not forget to accept my answer!!

Comment: Hey are you checked my edits 1 and edits 2? please support me if it works!!

Comment: It's not showing any result. not getting any output, you can see here b2b.routemate.in/view-book.php?packid=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157276/discussion-between-revati-and-animesh-sahu).